# Vim: Case-insensitive ex command completion

Tags: vim, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I'd like to have case-insensitive ex command completion in Vim.

I can accomplish this with:

```
set ignorecase
" Maybe with
set smartcase
```

However, the problem with this is that this (obviously) makes the search with `/` case-insensitive, which I don't want.

https://github.com/thinca/vim-ambicmd

This plugin did enable case-insensitive ex command completion (and even more functionality), but it also disabled the completion after that. For example, when I mapped `<Tab>` to the "expand" key, `:NeoBundleUpdate <Tab>` didn't list all the plugins managed by neobundle.vim but entered the `<Tab>` character.

I tried doing something like:

```
nmap / :set noignorecase<CR>/
nmap : :set ignorecase<CR>:
```

but this made Vim go crazy...

Is there any way I can achieve my goal of having case-insensitive command completion while retaining case-sensitive search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The help :h /c says:

```
7. Ignoring case in a pattern                                   /ignorecase

If the 'ignorecase' option is on, the case of normal letters is ignored.
'smartcase' can be set to ignore case when the pattern contains lowercase
letters only.
                                                        /\c /\C
When "\c" appears anywhere in the pattern, the whole pattern is handled like
'ignorecase' is on.  The actual value of 'ignorecase' and 'smartcase' is
ignored.  "\C" does the opposite: Force matching case for the whole pattern.
{only Vim supports \c and \C}
Note that 'ignorecase', "\c" and "\C" are not used for the character classes.

Examples:
      pattern   'ignorecase'  'smartcase'       matches
        foo       off           -               foo
        foo       on            -               foo Foo FOO
        Foo       on            off             foo Foo FOO
        Foo       on            on                  Foo
        \cfoo     -             -               foo Foo FOO
        foo\C     -             -               foo
```

That would suggest something like `nnoremap / /\c` or \C (if you need to change case-sensitivity) in your proposed way.

Comment: Awesome! Minor thing, but uppercase `\C` worked for me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the 'wildignorecase' option.

Comment: That's closer to what I want, but I also want user-defined commands to be case-insensitive; not just the files and directories.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Put `set wildignorecase` in `~/.vimrc`. [Reference](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wildignorecase%27)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep `ignorecase` and `smartcase` for command-line completion and make your search case-sensitive with this mapping:

```
nnoremap / /\C
```

See `:help \C`.

Answer (score 0):

After getting a hint from @mike that going down the `nmap` path is the right way, I came up with the following functions:

```
nnoremap : :call IgnoreCase()<CR>:
function! IgnoreCase()
    set ignorecase
endfunction
nnoremap / :call NoIgnoreCase()<CR>/
function! NoIgnoreCase()
    set noignorecase
endfunction
```

This solved my problem just how I wanted. The only tiny thing that bugs me is that the text `:call IgnoreCase()` flickers when I hit `:`, but I guess that can't be helped.

Comment: Regarding the verbose display of your command: I think there is a "silent" option somewhere,.. Please refer to the help/google. This should also be possible.

Comment: @mike `<silent>` mapping is no good because it doesn't show the `:` when I first hit it. The `:silent` command still shows the call to `IgnoreCase` because the whole `:silent call IgnoreCase()` is the one who's flickering. I think this is something that can't be helped.